# How to properly create pagination with knockout.js component?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, pagination

I'm working on building a component for a current and future projects that handles pagination on a knockout component level.  I've based the idea on the accepted answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17670390/7314155). Also reference the Knockout component page [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html).

Here is my component thus far. I am having trouble getting Any of the data to actually display, let alone with a dynamic table heading.

```
ko.components.register("jPage", {
viewModel: function (params) {
    var self = this;
    self.Items = params.Items;
    self.Keys = Object.keys(self.Items);
    self.PerPage = params.PerPage;
    self.Page = 1;
    self.PagesTotal = Math.ceil(self.Items.length / self.PerPage);

    self.ItemsVisible = ko.computed(function () {
        first = (self.Page * self.PerPage) - self.PerPage;
        return self.Items.slice(first, first + self.PerPage);
    })

    self.ChangePage = function (_page) {
        if (_page < 1 || _page > self.PagesTotal) return;
        this.Page(_page);
    }.bind(this);


},
template: 
    '<div data-bind="foreach: ItemsVisible"> \
        Display Table headers and data here <br>\
        <span data-bind="text: $data[0]"> </span>\
    </div>\
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation">\
    <ul class="pagination">\
        <li data-bind="css:{disabled: Page <= 1} ">\
            <a aria-label="Previous" data-bind="click: ChangePage( Page - 1 )">\
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>\
            </a>\
        </li>\
        <li><a data-bind="text: Page -2, click: ChangePage( Page - 2 ), visible: Page > 2 "> </a></li>\
        <li><a data-bind="text: Page -1, click: ChangePage( Page - 1 ), visible: Page > 1 "> </a></li>\
        <li class="active"><a data-bind="text: Page"> </a></li>\
        <li><a data-bind="text: Page +1, click: ChangePage( Page + 1 ), visible: (PagesTotal > Page +0) "></a></li>\
        <li><a data-bind="text: Page +2, click: ChangePage( Page + 2 ), visible: (PagesTotal > Page +1)"></a></li>\
        <li data-bind="css: {disabled: (PagesTotal < Page )}">\
            <a aria-label="Next" data-bind="click: ChangePage( Page + 1 )">\
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>\
            </a>\
        </li>\
    </ul>\
</nav>\
'
})
```

This is how the component would be called:

```
<div data-bind="component: { name: 'jPage', params: { Items: CustomerList(), PerPage: 25} }">
```

`CustomerList` would look like:

```
[
  {FirstName: "John", Email: "John@example.com"},
  {FirstName: "Steve", Email: "Steve@example.com"},
  {FirstName: "Jim", Email: "Jim@example.com"}
]
```

What variables or context am I missing to access `Items` keys/values?

Extra Notes. 
I do not have any required form of data as I can manipulate it without consequence.

Comment: First off in order to react to changes a property must be observable. So your Page property isn't going to do much as it stands. Once you fix that, and then all the references where it's used, a lot of your issues should disappear. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright. It took me 6 months to figure this out. But hopefully someone else will find this as valuable as I have.

The trick I found was not to use a component, but rather a template for only the HTML. Though I guess a component might work too.

Below is code for a view model for pagination and a small example of how it works. It only requires 1 input, an array, and then you simply bind the `PerPage`, and bind the output, `PaginatedArray`, and tah dah.

```js
function MainViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.ListOfStuff = ko.observableArray();

  self.Pagination = ko.observable(new PaginationVM(self.ListOfStuff));

  self.PopulateArray = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      self.ListOfStuff.push("Item " + i);
    }
  }
  self.PopulateArray();
}


function PaginationVM(input) {
  var self = this;
  self.InputArray = input;
  self.PerPage = ko.observable();
  self.Page = ko.observable(1);

  self.PageTotal = ko.computed(function() {
    var totalPages = Math.ceil(self.InputArray().length / parseInt(self.PerPage()));
    if (self.Page() > totalPages && totalPages > 0) {
      self.Page(totalPages);
    }
    return totalPages
  })

  self.PaginatedArray = ko.computed(function() {
    var perPage = parseInt(self.PerPage())
    var start = self.Page() * perPage - perPage;
    return self.InputArray().slice(start, start + perPage);
  })

  self.ChangePageBy = function(offset) {
    return function() {
      self.Page(self.Page() + offset);
    }
  }

  self.ChangePageTo = function(newPage) {
    return function() {
      switch (newPage) {
        case "last":
          self.Page(self.PageTotal());
          break;
        case "first":
          self.Page(1);
          break;
        default:
          self.Page(newPage);
      }
    }
  }
}


ko.applyBindings(new MainViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- This is the template needed for the view model but you can style it as necessary 
Its bootstrap right now.-->
<script type="text/html" id="PaginationTemplate">
  <nav class="text-center" aria-label="Page navigation">
    <ul class="pagination" style="cursor:pointer">
      <li data-bind="css:{disabled: Page() <= 1} ">
        <a aria-label="Previous" data-bind="click: ChangePageTo('first')">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-bind="text: Page() -2, click: ChangePageBy(-2), visible: Page() > 2 "> </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-bind="text: Page() -1, click: ChangePageBy(-1), visible: Page() > 1 "> </a>
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        <a data-bind="text: Page() "> </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-bind="text: Page() +1, click: ChangePageBy(1), visible: (PageTotal() > Page() +0)"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-bind="text: Page() +2, click: ChangePageBy(2), visible: (PageTotal() > Page() +1)"></a>
      </li>

      <li data-bind="css: {disabled: (PageTotal() < Page() +1)}">
        <a aria-label="Next" data-bind="click: ChangePageTo('last')">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</script>


<!-- This is what it looks like without pagination.
<div data-bind="foreach: ListOfStuff">
  <span data-bind="text: $data"> </span><br>
</div>-->
<select data-bind="value: Pagination().PerPage">
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="25">25</option>
                                <option value="50">50</option>
                                <option value="100">100</option>
                            </select>
<div data-bind="foreach: Pagination().PaginatedArray">
  <span data-bind="text: $data"></span><br>
</div>
<div data-bind="template: { name : 'PaginationTemplate', data: Pagination }">
```