# "for loop" for knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, loops, knockout.js

I have a page, containing a lot of items (observablearray), so I've created a paging system. (Well, not created myself, but copied from here [How to handle pagination with Knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668491/how-to-handle-pagination-with-knockout) ;) )

I want to show the individual buttons per page.
Something like:

```
<  1 2 3 4  >
```

I have the "totalPages" property, but how can I use that in on the frontend?

How can I loop through a knockout int-variable and create links to a function with that same int?

I was hoping something like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: totalPages">
    <li><a href="#" data-bind="text: $index, click: pageNumber($index)"></li>
</ul>
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to create an empty array and use it in `foreach`. Add a wrapper for the `click` function to get the `$index() + 1` as a parameter:

```js
const viewModel = {
  totalPages: ko.observable(4),
  pageNumber: n => console.log(n)
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: Array.from({ length: totalPages() })">
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-bind="text: $index() + 1, click: () => $parent.pageNumber($index() + 1)"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```